# How to introduce a static name in a class to a scope?

Tags: c++

For example

```
struct A
{
    static void foo();
    static void foo(int);
    static void foo(double, char);
    ...
};
```

and in a scope

```
namespace nm
{
    using A::foo; // not right
}
```

How to introduce a static name in a class to a scope?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

n3376 7.3.3/8

> A using-declaration for a class member shall be a member-declaration.
>
> ```
> struct X {
> int i;
> static int s;
> };
> void f() {
>    using X::i; // error: X::i is a class member
>    // and this is not a member declaration.
>    using X::s; // error: X::s is a class member
>    //and this is not a member declaration.
> ```
>
> }

n3376 7.3.3/3

> In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, the nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of the class being defined.

Comment: I think it makes sense for static members if c++ changes their standard.